# How to split a string on consecutive amounts of only letter or nonletter characters

Tags: regex, vb.net, string, split

I'm looking to specially split a string based on certain criteria. I'd like for any words (that is, consecutive amounts of only letter characters) to each be returned, as well as any non-words.

To illustrate what I mean, let's say I have the string **"Each of the past 20 nights, John has gone to bed at 11:00 pm."** (without quotes).
I'd like this split to return an array of strings =

```
{
"Each",
" ",
"of",
" ",
"the",
" ",
"past",
" 20 ",
"nights",
", ",
"John",
" ",
"has",
" ",
"gone",
" ",
"to",
" "
"bed",
" ",
"at",
" 11:00 ",
"pm",
"."
}
```

I'm not very familiar with regular expressions, but I'm hoping there might be a solution here!

Comment: @sloth: "consecutive amounts of only letter characters" + "as well as any non-words."

Comment: remove the commas and then split with space.

Comment: @Wooble Sometimes my reading ability just ... fails

Comment: @Meysam: That wouldn't generate anything close to the desired result. Test it and see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's easy with a regular expression:

```
Dim s = "Each of the past 20 nights, John has gone to bed at 11:00 pm."
Dim result = Regex.Split(s, "(\p{L}+)").Skip(1).ToArray()
```

`\p{L}` matches any unicode code point belonging to the "letter" category, so `(\p{L}+)` means: match any one or consecutive letters and keep them in the result. `Regex.Split` does, well, split the string on that pattern.

---

Here's the same without LINQ:

```
Dim s = "Each of the past 20 nights, John has gone to bed at 11:00 pm."
Dim tmp = Regex.Split(s, "(\p{L}+)")
Dim result(tmp.Length - 2) As String
Array.Copy(tmp, 1, result, 0, tmp.Length - 1)
```

Comment: That sounds like exactly what I'm looking for, but I have to ask, would that only give me the string pieces that contain letters and totally omit the string pieces (without letters) in-between? Or would result contain exactly what I posted in the question?

Comment: @user3653667 The result is exactly what you posted.

Comment: It seems to be a syntax error though (Array doesn't have a Skip member)

Comment: @user3653667 Which .Net Framework version are you using? Also, import the `System.Linq` namespace.

Comment: I'm using version 4.5 with Visual Studio 2005. There doesn't seem to be a System.Linq namespace available for me to import :(

Comment: @user3653667 Version 4.5 with Visual Studio 2005? I don't think so. Visual Studio 2005 shipped with .NET Framework 2.0. The .Net framework 4.5 is shipped with Visual Studio 2012. Nonetheless, I edited my answer and added a version that works without Linq

Comment: Yep, I downloaded 4.5 from Microsoft a while back. If you're referring to the SDK, then it is indeed 2.0. I'll try out your new solution

Comment: Maybe you have the .Net framework 4.5 installed, but you can not create .Net 4.5 applications using Visual Studio 2005.

Comment: Fabulous solution. Thanks for sticking with this one!